# Can I double 16 gauge wire?

Tags: wire, amperage, gauge, outlet

I have seen several similar questions on the internet but I can't find a straight answer.
I have a ton of used single strand 16 gauge wire that I would like to use. I know that 16 gauge wire typically is suitable for 10 amp. If I double or triple the wire, can I use it on a standard 15 amp outlet?

Comment: That depends on your affinity to risk – how likely do you deem it that one of the strands then comes loose? Have you talked to your insurance about that? You don't tell us where you are, but building codes will also be not OK with this. Also, installation effort might very quickly eat up your saved money on actually buying the right wire.

Comment: Used copper wire may look OK but it may not be in terms of breakdown voltage. Take it to be melted down and buy some new wire with the proceeds from the melt-down. This is an engineering site and many of us will insist on good practices being used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to DIY.SE

Comment: It's for a shop I'm building. I'm in a very rural area in Arkansas and there is no building codes. So can it work, is it dangerous? How many amps can I run if I double it?

Comment: At the risk of being ostracized here, let me point out that rated ampacity for chassis wiring   is much higher than bundle rating, about 22A for 16AWG. So (just theoretically) several individual wires in parallel could be somewhat safer than a single one of same cross section (assuming good air cooling, of course). However taking into account loose strands and building code as @MarcusMüller pointed out, as well as worn out insulation I'd rather buy new wire for the build

Comment: Don't do it. The outlet screw terminals are designed for one wire. There are two screws for each line, but the second is for daisy-chaining.

Comment: @RandyWoodward There are building codes. Even if there's nothing else, the US has national building codes that always must be followed, regardless of what state or municipality you're in.

Comment: If you're in the US then doing this will violate the NEC ("code"). Violating the NEC means that if anything goes wrong and your house burns down, you insurance won't pay up because you did this to yourself. There are some limited circumstances where using multiple wired to make up a larger 'ampacity' is "code-legal", but this only happens when you get to very large wires.

Comment: @brhans It was hell getting the inspector to approve some cable runs we laid in an industrial site where the workers laid down 3 thinner cables instead of one big one. It didn't match any pre-approved configuration in the NEC so we had buy software to run simulations of the cable bundle in the conduit buried in the soil to prove to the inspector it wouldn't overheat and burst into flames. My manager had initially asked me to research how to do the calculations by hand. Basically came back after reading IEEE and said "yeah...not happening".

Comment: By single-strand, do you mean cabling intended for mains lighting, or for more general use inside electrical equipment?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. Long answer, hell no. If one of the wires loses contact all the current is carried by the unbroken wire. That’s a fire hazard. Even if your local code enforcement doesn’t care, your insurance (and / or your neighbor’s insurance) will care if the building catches fire and they discover substandard wiring. And they know to look - about half of household fires are caused by electrical fault.

Not only that, it will be an issue when you sell your property. You’d need to disclose that the wiring isn’t up to code (which it wouldn’t be if you used #16 for any structure wiring.)

For a shop this is especially important, as the outlets get used for high-amperage power tools, heaters and other appliances. Don’t cut corners here. For your own safety, and that of others, do it right. Recycle your old stuff and get new wire that’s rated for your use. Use #14 for lighting (15A breaker) and #12 for outlets (20A breaker) as specified by code. If you’re not sure about any of this, consult an electrician (what about your feed from the panel? Sub-panel?)

You could still use the #16 for low-voltage stuff so long as you don’t exceed its capacity. It’s common in landscape lighting for example. But not for your building fixed wiring.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe or sensible. Here are some reasons:

- When you make a joint at the end, it often happens that one or more strands are not properly clamped and will shake loose. This is likely to cause a short circuit and also reduces the capacity of the line.
- The insulation is probably not suitable for mains voltages. Single-strand wire often has insulation with insufficient voltage rating. It may sort of work for a while, but it will not be damage tolerant and may quickly degrade, becoming brittle and start cracking up. The fact that it is already second hand means it may already be damaged or starting to degrade. Using it is a great way to start a fire.
- The rated current assumes good ventilation. Bundled up in a cable and buried behind stuff, heat cannot easily escape and the maximum safe current will be a lot less. Another great way to melt the insulation and cause one of the above outcomes.
- If your insurance company find out, they will not pay up. Knowing insurance companies, if you make a claim for some other reason and their inspector spots your wiring, they will not pay up on your policy at all.

My colleagues and I doubled or tripled strands of wire on rare occasions, but never for mains wiring.

Comment: "Single-strand wire is often rated at around 50 V working"... umm... I think the construction companies all around the world would be really surprised to hear this. "The rated current assumes good ventilation" only for _chassis wiring_. The usual rating for wire is given for _power transmission_ which assumes bundled cable.

Comment: @Maple Ah, I am thinking of what one might call component-grade wires. Something like mains lighting cable would be OK for voltage. I'd better ask the OP which they mean.